# Weird User in my login screen "puppet"

Tags: macos, user-account, login-screen

I just restarted my mac *"OSX El Capitan v10.11.1"* and I'm seeing a weird User in my login screen called *"puppet"*:

[image]

I have not created this User and I don't know how to log on it.

The most concerning part is that I'm not able to delete it because I can't find it in the *System Preferences > Users & Groups*:

[image]

Neither in the `/Users` folder:

```
$ ls -l /Users/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 11 Guest     _guest   374 Nov 23  2013 Guest
drwxrwxrwt   6 root      wheel    204 Oct 20 12:00 Shared
drwxr-xr-x+ 80 myuser    staff   2720 Dec  7 09:40 myuser
```

One explanation I can imagine is that the [automatization systems management tool I'm using (puppet)](https://puppetlabs.com/) has created this weird User.. but the other explanation I can imagine concerns me more: I've been hacked :/

Nothing in /etc/passwd:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep puppet # -> nothing
```

This file has been just created, looks like with my last restart:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/puppet.plist
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  2775 Dec  7 09:38 /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/puppet.plist
```

Have someone an explanation for this? How can I delete that User?

Comment: Is it in /etc/passwd?

Comment: @CedricH. nothing there, check the update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per puppet [doc](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_osx.html#create-users) for mac installation:

> The puppet master service needs a puppet user and group.

So you can be sure now that you haven't been hacked :)

Comment: Wow.. the puppet people should put this in red letters all around their website.. it is very weird to see a _magic User_ in your system with such a hacker-likely name :)

Comment: Well, if you copy&pasted puppet recipies from random web sites, you will be hacked sooner or later anyway. These recipies have root access...

Comment: @fguillen - I am not surprised they don't as if they understood OS X then the user would not appear. If the user id is less than 500 it does not appear as a login but just as a plain Unix login

Answer (score 3):

FYI, you can hide this user from the login screen:

```
sudo dscl . create /Users/puppet IsHidden 1
```

Or in pre-Yosemite versions:

```
defaults write  /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow HiddenUsersList -array-add puppet
```

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203998)